# Set VLANs via MAC address

Tags: networking, router

Im setting up a VLAN for a network with switches and a router.

It got me thinking that setting VLANs based upon ports, creates a fragile network which will be hard to maintain. eg. if someone unplugs a something from a port on a switch to test it and then replaces it in the wrong port the VLANs wont work.

Is there another way to make / set VLANs based upon Mac addresses or other, so its not based on a per port basis.

Comment: Because VLANs are configured on the switches and routers, this will require the switches and routers to support this. So, please add the switch brands/models you're working with to your question. Also, what has your research showed you? https://www.google.com/search?q=assign+vlan+by+mac+address

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/593416/cisco-switch-vlaning-based-on-mac-address

Comment: It is possible, depending on the hardware/software you have. Here are a few links with some information. [Answer from Network Engineering SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42359/assign-wireless-devices-to-vlan-by-mac-address) also [info from Cisco Support Forum](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/lan-switching-and-routing/assign-vlan-based-on-mac/td-p/2622878)